# Subclassing dictionary for use in external components

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary class which is used to store data, and which tracks hundreds of variables during the course of a session.
I have been tasked with building a common framework, which I can reference this base set of functionality, but allow the calling components to use different key and value within the dictionary.

Currently, this dictionary uses a 4-part tuple as the key, and a 2-part value.
The two components I'm tying into has a different key and value layout.
Component 1 - key is a 5-part tuple, and value is a 3-part.
Component 2 - Key is a 3-part tuple (string, int, string) and the same 2-part value.

This class handles data transfer to other components, so to avoid duplication of effort, want to keep as much of the common functionality in the Common dll, and external components would use the Survey class which the different key/value.  Not certain I'm explaining it well enough.
I have included the current code below.
Seems to me, if the main Survey is created with object, object, and subclass the external components with the correct key/value pair.

```
public sealed class Survey
{
    #region Private Objects
    private Survey()
    {

    }
    private Dictionary<SurveyKey, SurveyValue> survey = new Dictionary<SurveyKey, SurveyValue>();
    private int maxLines = 50000;

    private bool AllowLogging { get => (survey.Count > maxLines); }
    #endregion

    private void WriteData(SurveyKey key, SurveyValue value)
    {
        if (AllowLogging)
        {
            if (!survey.ContainsKey(key))
                survey.Add(key, value);
            else
                survey[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
#region SurveyValue Class
public sealed class SurveyValue
{
    public SurveyValue(int? value = null, string detail = null)
    {
        Detail = detail;
        Value = value;
    }

    // Uses an either/or value; Value or Detail
    public string Detail { get; private set; }
    public int? Value { get; private set; }
}
#endregion
#region SurveyKey Class
public sealed class SurveyKey : Tuple<string, string, string, string>
{
    public SurveyKey(string Signal, string SignalType, string Name, string OverallType) : base(Signal, SignalType, Name, OverallType) { }
    public string Signal { get => Item1; }
    public string SignalType { get => Item2; }
    public string Name { get => Item3; }
    public string OverallType { get => Item4; }
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `class Survey<TKey, TValue> { private Dictionary<TKey,TValue> survey = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()`

Comment: Would a single dictionary need to support multiple key formats or would each key/value structure use it's own dictionary?

Comment: There would be a single dictionary in the external components, each with a different key/value pair.  As stated below, I was overthinking my issue. The solution was very simple as Scott also pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Make your common class generic of type K,V and use the *where* keyword to restrict the dictionary K and V to KBaseClass and VBaseClass. Component1 can expose KBaseClass and VBaseClass derived types and inherit from common or reuse common.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was over thinking this problem.  All I need to do is create my base dictionary as Survey, and use this in my external components.
For some reason I was thinkning I needed to create an interface to allow the plugging in of the base dictionary.

```
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> survey = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
```